# Getting error 'property code not found on object of type NSError'

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

Suddenly my project started giving error from AFNetworking SDK.I am getting this error in all my project. I clone old repository which was working earlier but this are not working right now.

NSError class not able to access code property.
[image]

Comment: Swift with AFNetworking? Not Alamofire?

Comment: Yes, i'm using AFNetworking...but this error is coming in FBSDK also, not specific to this library

Comment: That is Objective-C, not Swift.

Comment: i am getting these error from sdk.